# How to add custom View according to UIButton location in swift?

Tags: swift, swift3, uiview

I am trying to add custom View on button action. custom View is add successfully, but it's not show properly

```
@IBAction func sideButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sideSubView = SideView(frame: CGRect(x: sender.frame.origin.x ,y: sender.frame.origin.y + 40,width: 200,height: 200))
    self.view.addSubview(sideSubView)
}
```

In UIView class

```
func xibSetup() {
    view = loadViewFromNib()
    view.frame = bounds
    view.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleHeight]
    addSubview(view)
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    xibSetup()
}
```

[image]

In screenshot, blue View is custom view, it's not show properly, I have set height and width is 200.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The screenshot shows the code working as it should. Your view starts underneath the button and moves right. I'm assuming that you wanted the whole 200 width and height visible under the button. If that is the case, then you need to change this line

```
sideSubView = SideView(frame: CGRect(x: sender.frame.origin.x ,y: sender.frame.origin.y + 40,width: 200,height: 200))
```

to

```
sideSubView = SideView(frame: CGRect(x: sender.frame.origin.x + sender.frame.size.width - 200 , y: sender.frame.origin.y + sender.frame.size.height, width: 200, height: 200))
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use this,

```
sideSubView = SideView(frame: CGRect(x: sender.frame.origin.x - 200 ,y: sender.frame.origin.y + 40,width: 200,height: 200))
```

Answer (score 0):

Its look like your button on Navigationbar and you are adding blue view on controller's view. Both view are different so point coordinate will be different for both.
You need to pass relative coordinate to your blue view's frame.